# Are there any examples on the use of the frequency spectrum between 40 and 42 GHz?

Tags: rf, high-frequency, spectrum

Since everyone started talking about 5G, I got curious about some parts of the frequency spectrum.
I found out that some operators in the U.S. asked FCC if they could free the range between 40 and 42 GHz to make use of this band for mobile comms. FCC denied the proposal (page 64 of [this document](https://apps.fcc.gov/edocs_public/attachmatch/FCC-17-152A1_Rcd.pdf)) at the end of November 2017. In the same document I read that this particular portion of spectrum is reserved to satellite comms.
I could not find anything else related about the rest of the world, except a couple of links about generic satellite uses.

So my question is: is there any specific example about the use of this spectrum portion? Is there any other use excluding satellites?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could be found by simple googling.

Comment: It's ok of you and other people want to, but you start from the wrong assumption I haven't tried Google yet. Aside from sat comms (and some other stuff I can very much relate to it), I was interested in understanding if there is any other interesting thing out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it easily by googling: -

[image]

The above is an extract from a document entitled "United States Frequency Allocations; the radio spectrum". There are similar such documents for the UK etc..

Comment: Well yes, but those tables are somewhat old and I was instead curious about new uses of this particular band. As I already mentioned, I found stuff about satellite comms (exactly what I see in this table), but nothing new / very different.